# Perl regular expression format /()/, /[]/ and // differences

Tags: regex, perl

How does the following make differences in Perl regex syntax?

```
if /\d+/
if /[\d]+/
if /(\d+)/
```

Answer (score 4):

They all the same, except the third creates a capture group.

See [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)